# How to execute, Startup Sql for teradata in Pyspark using JDBC

Tags: pyspark, jdbc, teradata

I have set RUNSTARTUP=ON in teradata JDBC connection parameter to execute startup sql. I am not aware where/how to specify startup sql to write spark dataframe in teradata.

I would like to execute below startup SQL prior to write dataframe. I request anyone please advise me with reference code as i am really in the need of covering the requirement.

**Startup SQL:**

```
"SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON"
```

**Connection URL:**

```
conn_url = "jdbc:teradata://HostName/tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF16,RUNSTARTUP=ON"
```

**Write Dataframe in teradata (Pyspark):**

```
df.repartition(1).write.format('jdbc')
.option('driver','com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver')
.option('url','tera_url')
.option('user','tera_user_name')
.option('password', tera_user_pwd)
.option('dbtable',TargetTeradataTableName)
.mode('overwrite')
.save()
```

I would like to execute the startup sql in teradata via JDBC in Pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

The "startup SQL" string is a predefined attribute of the user. It's not something passed as part of the request. It should be a single statement or a valid multistatement request, up to 255 Unicode characters, and must include an ending semicolon.

```
MODIFY USER tera_user_name AS STARTUP = 'SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON;';
```

The `MODIFY` can be executed by a DBA (someone with DROP USER permission) or by the user. Then RUNSTARTUP=ON will execute the SQL automatically at logon.